# How to change button image on click Unity

Tags: image, button, unity-game-engine, uibutton

I got unlock button for game, it works,but I want to user himself can press button, and then button image change. As you can see in code below when score is >= 10, buttons image change immediately. How can I achieve that?

```
public GameObject lockBtn;
Image lockComp;
public Sprite myLockImage;
public Sprite myLockSecondImage;
/////////////////////////////////////////

 lockComp = lockBtn.GetComponent<Image> ();

        if (bestScore >= 10) {
            lockComp.sprite = myLockImage;
        }
        else
        {
            lockComp.sprite = myLockSecondImage;
        }
```

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile as it is not put in a function. Why not include exactly what you have?

Comment: it is, i just cut code for example

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an event listener to your button so as to change the image.

```cs
    lockComp.sprite = myLockSecondImage;
    if (bestScore >= 10) {
        lockBtn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.addEventListener( OnLockButtonClicked ) ; 
    }

    // ...
    private void OnLockButtonClicked()
    {
         lockComp.sprite = myLockImage ;
    }
```

**Be carefull** to not add this snippet of code into the Update function. Otherwise, you will add a new event listener **every frame**

---

Saving the "unlocked state" of the button into a file so as to not show the unlocked sprite when the user starts the game again could be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in a **file** and **class** named `ButtonScript` and in a **method** named `OnButtonClick()`

```
public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public void OnButtonClick(){
        lockComp = lockBtn.GetComponent<Image> ();
        if (bestScore >= 10) {
            lockComp.sprite = myLockImage;
        }
        else
        {
            lockComp.sprite = myLockSecondImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this script on your *Button* and in the **OnClick** event add a reference to the *Button* and his *Method*:

[image: OnClick event]